Hydrogen with MIDI
I'm trying to use Hydrogen to play beats - or trying to. I've used QJackCtrl to attach it to the Virtual Keyboard and the Jack Keyboard. I attached it to SuperCollider and send every Midi Note from every channel.
The blue MIDI light flashes, but it's not playing any sound.  The amplitudes are turned up in the Mixer and if I click on the little play button in the mixer, I can hear the drum I click on.  Somehow, it's getting the MIDI but not playing it.
In the preferences, I've set it to use ALSA midi. It's listening to every channel.
What step have I missed??
I'm on Ubuntu 23.10, and I installed the Ubuntu Studio packages. I've got Hydrogen 1.2.0-beta.

The answer turned out to be to download an AppImage from the Hydrogen website directly. http://hydrogen-music.org/downloads/
Debian and Ubuntu are both sticking with this beta version, despite it being a beta that is several years old that has some serious bugs.
